# Google Maps MapTypeControl position issue

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When positing *mapTypeControl* (Satellite, Terrain) to BOTTOM_LEFT/BOTTOM_CENTER/BOTTOM_RIGHT, it sets the controls too low, so when clicking on *Satellite* the sub-option becomes cutoff.

This issue is viewable here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-positioning

Left and Right side have solution by placing the controls in LEFT_BOTTOM/RIGHT_BOTTOM.

Is it possible to position it a bit higher in the center position?

Thanks

Comment: That looks like an issue with the Google Maps Javascript API v3, probably should be added to the [issues list](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/), I would think that should work out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will search a bit more about this issue, if nothing comes up i´ll add it to gmaps api issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same issues. You can find all the available [Positions here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/control#ControlPosition). You might want to use `LEFT_BOTTOM`: "Elements are **positioned on the left, above bottom-left elements**, and flow upwards."

Worst case scenario try `LEFT_CENTER` position.

```
  +----------------+
  + TL    TC    TR +
  + LT          RT +
  +                +
  + LC          RC +
  +                +
  + LB          RB +
  + BL    BC    BR +
  +----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the dropdown to make it appear above the button with the following CSS:

```css
.gm-style-mtc div[role="button"] + div {
  top: -90px !important;
}
```

The `top` negative px amount will depend on your button size setting (e.g. `controlSize: 30`).

Answer (score 0):

Create custom buttons like this:

```
// css
toggleGroup: {
    position: 'absolute',
    boxShadow: `rgb(0 0 0 / 30%) 0px 1px 4px -1px`,
    bottom: '35px',
    left: '10px',
    '& .MuiToggleButton-root': {
      fontSize: '18px',
      color: 'rgb(86, 86, 86)',
    },
    '& .MuiToggleButton-root.Mui-selected': {
      color: '#000',
      fontWeight: 700
    },
  }

// toggle method
const handleToggle = (_e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>, view: ViewType) => {
    if (map === null) {
      return;
    }

    if (view !== null) {
      setView(view);
      view === ViewType.SATELLITE ? map.setMapTypeId('hybrid') : map.setMapTypeId('roadmap');
    }
  };

// component
<ToggleButtonGroup
    value={view}
    className={classes.toggleGroup}
    onChange={handleToggle}
    aria-label='Select Map Type'
    exclusive>
      <ToggleButton value={ViewType.MAP}>Map</ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value={ViewType.SATELLITE}>Satellite</ToggleButton>
 </ToggleButtonGroup>
```